# Writing bold text with UTL_FILE package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Could anyone please share how to write bold text to a .dat file using something similar to the below or otherwise in PL/SQL?

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(FPOINTER,'i want this in bold');
```

Comment: There's a difference between data (e.g. text) and the way it is rendered for display (e.g. bold font). UTL_FILE is agnostic of the data you send to the file, it's up to you to determine whether the data format of the file allows formatting instructions, and what format should be used to encode those instructions. One example is HTML as given by Troydm.

Answer (score 6):

I think I maybe wrong but you can't do text with styles with UTL_FILE. .dat usually is used for information only, and its representation (like bold texts) is not part of it.

However you can save file as HTML and put lines like `'<b>'|| 'my text here' || '</b>'`